Drizzle one to many relation to the same table
I have a table of articles, an article can have a parent article. Meaning that a parent article references many child articles.
I can't find a way to query for all articles and join their child articles.
Thanks for helping me out.
This is in my schema.ts file:
export const articles = pgTable('articles', {
    id: uuid('id').defaultRandom().primaryKey(),
    title: varchar('title', { length: 600 }).notNull(),
    description: varchar('description'),    
    parentArticleId: uuid('parent_article_id').references(() => articles.id)
});
export const childArticlesRelation = relations(articles, ({ many }) => ({
    childarticles: many(articles, { relationName: 'childarticles' })
}));

And now I want to query for articles and join their child articles:
db.query.articles
        .findMany({
                where: and(...filter),
                with: {
                        childarticles: true
                }
         });

That gives me:
There is not enough information to infer relation "articles.childarticles"
Which I understand, but I can't find anything in the docs that gives me the correct syntax.

Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77452813/how-can-i-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-to-the-same-table-with-drizzle-and

I solved it by adding the proper relationName:
export const articleChildrenRelation = relations(articles, ({ many }) => ({
    childarticles: many(articles, { relationName: 'childarticles' })
}));


export const childArticleRelation = relations(articles, ({ one }) => ({
    parentArticle: one(articles, {
       fields: [articles.parentArticleId],
       references: [articles.id],
       relationName: 'childarticles'
    })
}));


also came to this problem basically you need to give same name for the relationName
example
export const category = pgTable("category", {
  id: uuid("id").primaryKey().defaultRandom(),
  name: varchar("name", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
  parent_id: uuid("parent_id"),
});

export const category_relations = relations(
  category,
  ({ one, many }) => ({
    parent: one(category, {
      fields: [category.parent_id],
      references: [category.id],
      relationName: "categories", // this and
    }),
    categories: many(category, {
      relationName: "categories", // this should be same
    }),
  })
);


I had a similar problem, solved this by creating a view of the same table, and then joining on the view instead.
This then allowed me to do a join on the same table, unfortunately there was also another step, not sure if this is sqlite problem but I also needed to alias the fields in the second view, otherwise it seems to have field ambiguity.
eg. lets assume I had a table with a field id, inside the view I would define the id like ->
id2: sql<number>`id`.as('id2')

There might be an easier way to create an alias field in a view but that worked for me.
Using a view also still made indexes etc worked as expected, again this was in sqlite and doing a EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN, every was good.
There might be an easier way than this, but did try doing some searching and couldn't find anything, so I'll be placing a watch on this thread if anyone else has a better approach.
